# systemd-journald[1016]: Failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: crash, systemd-journald, squashfs

This message appears on the startup/shutdown terminal, and I am unable to power off the machine. I am first going to drain the battery, and hope that it comes back to life after restart. Here is the situation.

I started the reset process after installing the Ubuntu Desktop ISO image. I created a profile. As the restart was starting I took out the Ubuntu USB with the ISO on it. All of a sudden my screen was filled with console messages running with text stating:

> systemd-journald[1016]: Failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Transport enpoint is not connected

This script is now frozen and my keyboard does not seem to be working, however I can turn my <kbd>Fn</kbd> lock on and off, but there are no power options.

Apparently it has something to do with my fragment cache entry.

I have plugged the USB flash drive back in, and now I'm getting this message:

> SQUASHFS error: unable to read page, block 405819c, size c207

and now back to:

> systemd-journald[1016]: Failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Transport endpoint is not connected

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Stsv6cPdlXE) taught me that there are different length hard shutdowns.

Comment: *squashfs* errors are representative of inability to read the squashed file-system, used prior to install. If you removed your install media, then re-inserted it, you'll have an *unstable* system until you reboot (*squashfs* errors are a symptom of that; inability to read the removed media). Is this an installed system?  What Ubuntu system?  as you've not specified clearly (ie. which Ubuntu Desktop ISO as there are many available for download).

Comment: FYI:  Even with a stuck GUI/screen, you can still direct the kernel if you have a real keyboard attached (*it can't be a on-screen keyboard, which requires GUI to be functional*). Pull out a phone & search "magic sysrq" and follow wikipedia page clues if you aren't are.. it allows you to safely tell machine to reboot (eg. SysRq REISUB) or turn off (REISUO) etc and is safer than power button... It won't work if kernel panic (but machine will be dead inc. no messages if that's so!)

Answer (score 1):

Hold the power button down for 20 seconds, and wait for 5 minutes before powering it back on.